# How to pass Select value from Javascript to PHP to generate select option on change

Tags: php, ajax, javascript

This is my code which generates locations:

```
<select name="filter-location" id="location">
    <option value="">
        <?php if ( $input_titles == 'placeholders' ) : ?>
        <?php echo __( 'Location', 'realia' ); ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo __( 'All locations', 'realia' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </option>
    <?php
        $locations = get_terms('locations', array(
            'hide_empty'    => false,
            'parent'        => 0
        ));
    ?>
    <?php if ( is_array( $locations ) ) : ?>
    <?php foreach ( $locations as $location ) : ?>
    <option value="
        <?php echo esc_attr( $location->term_id ); ?>" 
        <?php if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-location'] ) && $_GET['filter-location'] == $location->term_id ) : ?>selected="selected"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?php echo esc_html( $location->name ); ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

[image: Locations]

And this is the code which generates districts:

```
<?php $sublocations = get_terms('locations', array(
                                'hide_empty' => false,
                                'parent' => $location->term_id,
                               ));
?>
```

[image: Districts]

As you can see, to generate districts, it needs `$location->term_id`.

How can I send `$location->term_id` whenever someone selects a location?

Comment: you need `ajax`

Comment: yes i know but my problem is  how

Comment: can you update your question stating that you are doing it with Ajax and code of what you accomplished so far?

Comment: So you need to generate a option field based on the selected value of another option field, right ?